# Return highlighted keyword in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ Query:

```
var list = (from k
                    in this.Entities.TblNewsKeywords
                    join a in this.Entities.TblNewsActivities
                    on k.ActivityId equals a.ID
                    where k.Keyword.Contains(keyword) || a.Name.Contains(keyword)
                    orderby a.Date
                    select a);
```

How can I highlight the matching keyword/keywords in LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is a querying language. You cannot highlight anything with it. Get the results and let your interface deal with them.

Comment: @jyparask you are right. After the LINQ Query or in the MVC view then?

Comment: Add MVC related tags and probably post the code of your View. The more precise you are, the better the answer you'll get.